# Where is ASP.NET Core Identity's password policy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I created the ASP.NET Core Web Application (target .NET Core 3.1) MVC with `Individual User Accounts` Authentication option.

[image]

When I run the program, I notice that there are password policy enabled for account `Register` function. My question where is the password policy code located at?

[image]

I didn't notice any password policy configuration at `Startup.cs`

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: If this duplicate doesn't help you, please state why

Comment: My question is where is the default code which enable and configure those password policy. After I have identify this, then only next I will look into how to override it.

Comment: Did you look at the duplicate ?

Comment: Yes, but I can't see anywhere that it mentioned on `where` the default password policy is configured. Anyway, I have just found out the location of it.